# Image does not change when adding an alpha channel

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, alpha

The pillow package has a method called [`Image.putalpha()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putalpha) which is used to add or change the alpha channel of an image.

I tried to play with this method and found that I can not change the background color of an image. The original image is

[image]

This is my code to add alpha to it

```
from PIL import Image

im_owl = Image.open("owl.jpg")

alpha = Image.new("L", im_owl.size, 50)
im_owl.putalpha(alpha)

im_owl.show()
```

The produced image is nothing different from the original image. I have tried with different value of alpha and see no difference.

What could have been wrong?

Comment: Aren't you suppose to first create the image with alpha channel? `cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA`

Comment: You can read the doc about `Image.putalpha()`, which does not require image to be with an alpha channel before hand. There is no OpenCV involved in this question.

Answer (score 2):

try to save the image and see it. 
I am also not able to see the image directly from

```
im_owl.show()
```

but when I saved it

```
im_owl.save()
```

I am able to see the image changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
im_owl.save("alphadOwl.png")
```

And then view the saved image. It would seem that the alpha channel isn't applied to bmp or jpg files. It is a bmp file that gets displayed with `im.show()`

(For the record, I'm on a mac, I don't know if `im.show()` uses different applications on other devices).

Comment: Thanks, it seems the image is shown as bmp file, which does not use alpha channel.

Comment: Might be worth looking at what happens when you read it back in to a PIL image - does the alpha channel remain?

Answer (score 1):

As @sanyam and @Pam have pointed out, we can save the converted image and it shows correctly. This is because on Windows, images are saved as temporary BMP file before they are shown using the system default image viewer, as per the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show):

```
Image.show(title=None, command=None)

    Displays this image. This method is mainly intended for debugging purposes.

    On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary PPM file, and calls
    either the xv utility or the display utility, depending on which one can be found.

    On macOS, this method saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and opens it with
    the native Preview application.

    On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the standard BMP
    display utility to show it (usually Paint).
```

To fix this issue, we can patch the Pillow code to use PNG format as default. First, we need to find the root of Pillow package:

```
import PIL
print(PIL.__path__)
```

On my system, the output is:

> [’D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL’]

Go to this directory and open the file `ImageShow.py`. I add the following code after the line `register(WindowsViewer)`:

```
    class WindowsPNGViewer(Viewer):
        format = "PNG"

        def get_command(self, file, **options):
            return ('start "Pillow" /WAIT "%s" '
                    '&& ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL '
                    '&& del /f "%s"' % (file, file))

    register(WindowsPNGViewer, -1)
```

After that, I can show the image with alpha channel correctly.

### References

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3695